# PhpStorm not detecting file changes until focussing on another app

Tags: phpstorm

Been running into some issues with PhpStorm (v2020.3 on MacOS Big Sur 11.1) lately.

If I make changes to a file and save them, it doesn't trigger actions like a file transfer or recompiling (S)CSS when running `npm run watch`.

As soon as I focus another application (e.g. the browser for previewing) it detects the changed file and runs the needed action. This causes an annoying delay in my workflow.

At first I thought it had to do with Docker not updating the files in the container, however I now figured out it also does not work with a simple automated (s)FTP file upload/deplyoment.

Anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Cheers,
Allard

Comment: Please enable `Preferences | Editor | General | Editor Tabs | Mark modified (*)` and check if the asterisk mark disappears from the tab name after the alleged save takes place.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, checked the box and after pressing `CMD + S` the asterisk sign remains there, so it appears the file is not saved upon pressing the `CMD + S` shortcut. 

When focussing another application the changed files are automatically saved. 

When pressing the `save all` shortcut, it does work and all files are saved and the asterisk is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by remapping the `Save document` shortcut under `Preferences > Keymap`. No idea how the shortcut got messed up, but hey, it works.

Comment: FYI: `Ctrl + S` (or `Cmd + S` on Mac I guess) by default should be assigned to "Save All" action. "Save Document" is a different action -- it save current file only (which is not a default behaviour).  Anyway: if that works for you then no probs.

Comment: Thanks, reset the shortcuts and all works perfectly now.